# Java HDF fsDataOutputStream write fails empty file creation

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am having a strange issue with write small files on hadoop. below is sample program

```
public void writeFile(Configuration conf, String message, String filename) throws Exception {
        FSDataOutputStream fsDataOutputStream = null;
        DistributedFileSystem fs = null;
        try {
            fs = (DistributedFileSystem) FileSystem.get(URI.create(properties.getHadoop().getRawLocation()), conf);
            Path hdfswritepath = new Path(properties.getHadoop().getRawLocation() + "/" + filename + ".json");
            fsDataOutputStream = fs.create(hdfswritepath);
            fsDataOutputStream.write(message.getBytes());
            fsDataOutputStream.close();
            fsDataOutputStream.hsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Got Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            fs.close();
            System.out.println("clean up done");
        }

    }
```

Above code is creating empty file at hadoop location. here are some on item I tried

1. Firewall is not there between client and hadoop server
2. Copy from local to hadoop is working.

**Issue is Only 0 byte file getting created.**

I am getting below exception for this.

```
09:12:02,129 INFO  [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient] (Thread-118) Exception in createBlockOutputStream: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by

> conf.set("dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname", "true");